# std::unique_ptr Attempting to reference a deleted function on trying to make a deep Copy

Tags: visual-c++, stl, unique-ptr

After searching all over and scratching my head a lot, I'm still not able to figure this out.  haven't used smart pointers,vectors much before. Please help.

I'm trying to make deep copy of class A and i'm getting this error. the Error points to microsoft's xutility.cpp's "Template Function Copy" if this matters.

```
classA
{
  public:
     ClassA (const ClassA& origClassA)
     {
         ClassA::Copy(origClassA);
     }

     ClassA & ClassA ::operator=(const ClassA & origClassA )
     {

         if (this != &origClassA )
        {
           ClassA ::Clear();
           ClassA ::Copy(origClassA );
         }

         return *this;
      }

      void ClassA ::Clear()
     {
        m_nId = 0;
        m_pType = nullptr;
      }

      void ClassA ::Copy(const ClassA & fromClassA )
      {
          m_nId = fromClassA .m_nId;

          if (fromClassA.m_pType)
          {
              if (!m_pType)
                m_pType = std::make_unique<int>();
              *m_pType = *fromClassA.m_pType;
           }

       }
   private:
        int m_nId;
        std::unique_ptr<int> m_pType;
   }

Class B
{
  public:
       ClassB(const ClassB& origClassB)
       {
         classB::Copy(origClassB);

       }

       classB& operator=(const classB& fromclassB)
       {
          if (this != &origClassA )
          {
             classB::Clear();
             classB::Copy(origClassA );
          }

          return *this;


       }

       void classB::Clear()
       {
          m_vectorclassA.Clear();
       }

       void Copy(const classB& fromclassB)
        {
            m_vectorclassA = fromclassB.m_vectorclassA;
        }


        void SetVector(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<classA>>& vectorclassA  )
        {
           std::vector<std::unique_ptr<classA>>::const_iterator Iterator;

           for (Iterator = vectorclassA.begin(); Iterator != vectorClassA.end(); Iterator++)
           {
              m_vectorclassA.push_back(std::make_unique<classA>(*(*Iterator)));
           }
       }

   private:
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<classA>> m_vectorclassA;
   }
```

Comment: `m_vectorclassA = fromclassB.m_vectorclassA` This attempts to make a shallow copy - it tries to copy pointers, not the data they point to. Of course, `unique_ptr` cannot be copied - that's what makes it "unique". Did you mean to call `SetVector` from `ClassB::Copy`?

Comment: **m_vectorclassA = fromclassB.m_vectorclassA ** This was it. I did not see it at all in my actual code which is way longer and pasted the simplified code. Thanks! Also, i did not mean to call **SetVector** from **ClassB::Copy**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**m_vectorclassA = fromclassB.m_vectorclassA**

Was the line causing the problem as pointed by  user Igor Tandetnik